# Stop cron job constantly rebooting ec2 instance

Tags: cron, amazon-ec2, aws

I created a script to reboot system when CPU load hit 90%. But for some testing purpose I changed the value of max CPU Utilisation to 0.7%.

The script is programmed to run system reboot.

Now the server is never online - it constantly reboots.

My script:

```
#!/bin/bash
dstat| awk '{ if (int($1)>0.7) { 
              i=i+1; {
                       print i, $1
               }
              }

           if (int($1)>0.7) {
           j=j+1;
           }   
           if (j>2) {
                  print "system reboot";
                  cmd="sudo reboot";
                  system(cmd)
           }
        }'
```

NB the script is programmed to run on reboot using crontab :

```
@reboot /bin/bash /ubuntu/home/reboot.sh
```

So I am unable to login using SSH. Because the system is constantly rebooting.

My server is an AWS ec2 instance

I have tried passing user data through aws console.

```
sudo apt-get purge dstat
cd /ubuntu/home && sudo rm reboot.sh
sudo /etc/init.d/cron stop
```

But it doesn't work.

So, any possible ways to get my instance back would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you set boot parameters? (I don't use AWS)

Comment: Idk how to set boot parameters. Thanks for suggesting though. :)
Actually i found the solution. 
I detached my root volume from the instance and attached/mounted it on my other instance and then i opened up the mounted volume and remove the script and then detached it and attached it as root volume to the original instance. 
This worked as the script required was no longer there. So the system booted up perfectly.  :)

Comment: You can put your own answer in and accept it then. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Stop the instance, and take a look to the EBS disk (write down the mountpoint)
2. Dettach the hard drive of the failing instance (EBS)
3. Boot up a new fresh instance (Ubuntu 18.04, RHEL, the one you feel more confortable with...)
4. Attach the failing disk to the new instance.
5. Mount the filesystem to `/mnt` (for example)
6. Remove the crontab rule you've added to CRONTAB (in `/etc/crontab/`... )
7. Detach the EBS disk
8. Attach to the failing machine again, using the same mountpoint
9. Boot your old machine as always; cron will be disabled
10. Remove the machine you've used to change the FS

It is a faily common pattern, to dettach a failing FS to another machine, fix whatever is preventing it to boot, and attach it again to the old host.

Hope it solves your problem.